# How can I see the mentioned PATH in this .Net error?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, assemblies

I am having an error which says:

"Failed to load the DLL, check that any DLLs it depends on are in the **PATH** (SomeLibrary.dll): The specified module could not be found."

I want to know where this DLL is looke up by .Net.

How can I see the PATH details it is relying to reach the dll mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated than you might think. It starts with the GAC but also looks in some other locations. This article seems to explain it well.

http://ihorwill.blogspot.com/2006/09/net-assembly-resolution.html

Comment: So do you think to get a copy of the relevant assembly to the local bin folder would help -as it is not in the GAC?